# How to validate multiple fields in one single function in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a function that needs to validate multiple text fields but cannot seem to get it right. I use `$("#textfield").blur(validation);` for example, to run the validation function when each field loses focus (all three fields call the validation function using `blur`). I think i'm not ordering the `if` statements correctly. Also, if you know a simpler way of doing the validation using `this` that would be also great. Thank you.

```
function validation(height,width,color){

if (height.length == 0 || height == null){ //check for empty field
  $("#msg").html("This field cannot be empty");
}
else if (isNaN(height)){ //check that height is a number
  $("#msg").html("The height must be a number"); 
}else{
  $("#msg").html("The height is " + height); //if height is ok shows this message
}
if (width.length == 0 || width== null){  //same for width
  $("#msg").html("This field cannot be empty");
}
else if (isNaN(width)){
  $("#msg").html("The width must be a number");
}else{
  $("#msg").html("The width is " + width);
}
if (color.length == 0 || color == null){
  $("#msg").html("This field cannot be empty");
}
else if (color == "white" || color == "grey"){ //check that color is one of these two options
  $("#msg").html("The color is " + color);
}else{
  $("#msg").html("The color must be white or grey");
}

}
```

Comment: you can simply use the bootstrap library for this work

Comment: HTML5 form validation helps you? No need to use scripts. Try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation).

Comment: @Doug the issue is that I am studying for a test, I need to do it like this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advised to check for the `null` first followed by `.length === 0`

At the least you can make a reusable `isNullOrEmpty` function -

```
   function isNullOrEmpty (obj) {
         return !((obj !== undefined) && (obj !== null) && (obj .length === 0));
    }
```

Then you can generalize like -

```
function validateNumber(obj ,fieldName) {
    if(isNaN(obj)) {
        return 'The ' + fieldName + ' must be number.'
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Can I evaluate multiple variables inside the `isNaN`?. like `isNaN(obj1,obj2,obj3)`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `if(!height) { $("#msg").text("Height is not defined") }`.This stands for false, undefined,NaN, zero and string empty values